# Know when vertical scrollbar hits bottom of scroll in div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I used following code but it is not working:

```
$("#divID").scroll(function(){
        if  ($("#divID").scrollTop() == $("#divID").height() - $("#divID").offset().top){
           alert(1);
        }
    });
```

`divID` is the id of div.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#divID").scroll(function(){
    if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).outerHeight())
    {
        alert(1);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/DgYcY/

Comment: It should be `==` instead of `<=`. [Here](http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/) is good explanation of this kind of code.

Comment: @Harry... actually it should be '===' and possibly `.outerHeight(true)`

Comment: I just tried the same thing and found == is too sensitive. Log those numbers to your console as you scroll and you'll see when you get to the very bottom it tends to invert.