# Detect div scroll bar hit the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

how to detect when div scroll bar, scroll up and hit the top(only when it hit the top)

I have found another post, but this one is hit the bottom.

what i need is hit the top. anyone know how to change this?

```
$("#divID").scroll(function(){
    if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).outerHeight())
    {
        alert(1);
    }
});
```

[Know when vertical scrollbar hits bottom of scroll in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383608/know-when-vertical-scrollbar-hits-bottom-of-scroll-in-div)

Comment: this seems very complicated,why not just try some thing simple!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLkmK/9/)

```
var el = $('.test');
el.on('scroll', function(){

    if(el.scrollTop() == 0){alert("i just hit the top")}


});
```

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` will be `0` when the scroll bar is that the top. Try this:

```
$("#divID").scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        alert(1);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XE42P/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divID").scroll(function(){
    if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).outerHeight())
    {
        alert("Bottom");
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() == 0)
    {
        alert("Top");
    }
});
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3RGPE/)